# SAML token Digital Signature issue (WSO2 version vs Standalone jars of xml signature)

Tags: wso2, xml-signature, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 to digitally sign and encrypt a message:

The web service is deployed on weblogic and is expecting a SAML token, and the body and headers and to be signed and ecrypted.

Scenario 1 : Use stand along axis api's (1.6.2 +) to generate a web service client for the wsdl with a policy expecting SAML token. The code generates a digitally signed and encrypted SOAP envelop, hits the endpoint and the result is returned successfully.

```
<ds:Reference URI="#c4243cf4c8b6b8d6bc6570af5c0573e6">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse wsu soapenv" />
        </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <ds:DigestValue>lWQgTrlIVeFKWqT1ktPs0/kK3tQ=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

Scenario 2: Use the same code from Scenario 1 from within WSO2 ESB 4.7, the above client goes as a class mediator and WSO2 ESB jars are used. The request SOAP envelope is perfectly signed and ecrypted except a change in XML syntax.

```
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-2003921168">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform
            Algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#STR-Transform">
            <wsse:TransformationParameters>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </wsse:TransformationParameters>
        </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <ds:DigestValue>mfNA+3ZPnCMzS2Y0TJ1GsYcdHNE=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

There seems to be a difference in the signatures generated in the two scenarios. Is WSO2 ESB implementation of XML security different from that of standalone apache XML security implementation ?

The SOAP envelope generated from scenario fails to get validated for this signature at the weblogic webserver and throws SOAP fault with the following stack trace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Failed to validate signature.</faultstring><detail><bea_fault:stacktrace xmlns:bea_fault="http://www.bea.com/servers/wls70/webservice/fault/1.0.0">weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityException: Failed to validate signature.
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityImpl.unmarshalAndProcessSignature(SecurityImpl.java:740)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityImpl.unmarshalAndProcessSignature(SecurityImpl.java:689)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityImpl.unmarshalChildren(SecurityImpl.java:544)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityImpl.unmarshalInternal(SecurityImpl.java:450)

Caused by: weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.api.XMLSignatureException
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.STRTransform.transform(STRTransform.java:303)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.ReferenceUtils.applyTransforms(ReferenceUtils.java:49)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.ReferenceImpl.createDigest(ReferenceImpl.java:161)

Caused by: weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityException: No token handler found for null
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityContext.getRequiredTokenHandler(WSSecurityContext.java:410)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.STRTransform.transform(STRTransform.java:193)

Caused by: weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.api.XMLSignatureException
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.STRTransform.transform(STRTransform.java:303)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.ReferenceUtils.applyTransforms(ReferenceUtils.java:49)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.ReferenceImpl.createDigest(ReferenceImpl.java:161)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.ReferenceImpl.validate(ReferenceImpl.java:116)
    at weblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureImpl.validate(XMLSignatureImpl.java:256)
```

The web service policy file used is:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsp:All>
        <ns1:AsymmetricBinding
            xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <ns1:InitiatorToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns1:X509Token
                            ns1:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <ns1:WssX509V3Token10 />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </ns1:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns1:InitiatorToken>
                <ns1:RecipientToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns1:X509Token
                            ns1:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <ns1:WssX509V3Token10 />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </ns1:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns1:RecipientToken>
                <ns1:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns1:Basic256 />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns1:AlgorithmSuite>
                <ns1:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns1:Lax />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns1:Layout>
                <ns1:IncludeTimestamp />
                <ns1:ProtectTokens />
                <ns1:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </ns1:AsymmetricBinding>

        <ns2:SignedSupportingTokens
            xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <ns2:IssuedToken
                    ns2:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                    <ns2:Issuer>
                        <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://HYD-69ZRV01-L:6002/standalonests/SamlSTS
                        </Address>
                    </ns2:Issuer>

                    <ns2:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                        <t:TokenType xmlns:t="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion
                        </t:TokenType>
                    </ns2:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>

                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns2:RequireInternalReference />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns2:IssuedToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <ns2:SamlToken
                    ns2:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns2:WssSamlV11Token10 />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns2:SamlToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </ns2:SignedSupportingTokens>

        <!-- 
        <ns2:SignedSupportingTokens
            xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <ns2:SamlToken
                    ns2:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <ns2:WssSamlV11Token10 />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </ns2:SamlToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </ns2:SignedSupportingTokens>
         -->

        <ns3:Wss10 xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <ns3:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
                <ns3:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </ns3:Wss10>


        <ns4:EncryptedParts
            xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <ns4:Body />
        </ns4:EncryptedParts>

        <ns5:SignedParts
            xmlns:ns5="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <ns5:Body />
        </ns5:SignedParts>

    </wsp:All>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the used Transform algorithm at 2 scenarios. That must be the cause of problem.

Comment: Pushpalanka, I can make it out from the difference. Is there a way where we specify the transformation algorithm to be used for digital signature when using Apache Rampart ?